# Like counter for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

so i created a counter for likes. i have 3 elements in total and i want when the user clicks on one of them that exact one is increment but so far if one is clicked on all are incremented pls help me out

```
class home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      likeCounter: 0,
    };
  }

  counter = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      likeCounter: prevState.likeCounter + 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button className="click" onClick={this.counter}>
          {this.state.likeCounter} likes
        </button>

        <button className="click" onClick={this.counter}>
          {this.state.likeCounter} likes
        </button>

        <button className="click" onClick={this.counter}>
          {this.state.likeCounter} likes
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are numerous syntax errors in your code. Maybe fix those first? Here is a short list: `this.state{` should probably be `this.state = {`, `this.setState((prevState)=>{` should probably be `this.setState((prevState)=>({` and closing tags use / instead of \ so it should be `</button>`...

Comment: @Dominik done, sorry about that i typed it on my phone from my laptop so i didn't notice those, thanks. but how to i make it increment for each and not for all when i click on one of the buttons

Comment: There were still issues. I fixed them up for you, feel free to revert if that was the problem in the first place.

Comment: Duplicate `id` is (almost certainly) your problem, use a class-name and iterate over the elements with that class. An `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

Comment: @David says reinstate Monica  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try it like this:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  counter = (counter) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      [counter]: prevState[counter] ? prevState[counter] + 1 : 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => this.counter(1)}>
          {this.state[1] ? this.state[1] : 0} likes
        </button>

        <button onClick={() => this.counter(2)}>
          {this.state[2] ? this.state[2] : 0} likes
        </button>

        <button onClick={() => this.counter(3)}>
          {this.state[3] ? this.state[3] : 0} likes
        </button>

        <button onClick={() => this.counter(4)}>
          {this.state[4] ? this.state[4] : 0} likes
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

After you changed your question about "How to make these three buttons work" to "I got lot's of buttons, how would I do that" I would recommend you to create a single component that does the likes and include it several times (written as a functional component):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function LikeBtn() {
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);

  return <button onClick={() => setLikes(likes + 1)}>{likes} likes</button>;
}

export default LikeBtn;
```

then use it in your app like this:

```
import React from "react";
import LikeBtn from "./LikeBtn";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LikeBtn />
      <LikeBtn />
      <LikeBtn />
      <LikeBtn />
      <LikeBtn />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it worked Thank you, but what of in a situation where i have more than 100 of those buttons would i create 100 states too (likeCounter1 : 0,) or there is a way to work around it

Comment: I updated the answer. Feel free to mark it as the answer if this works for you

Comment: Thank you for you time and help, will implement it right away

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use multiple like button, you should create a reusable one. just extract functionality of like button from `Home` component.

```
class LikeBtn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { likes: 0 };
  }

  inc = () => {
    this.setState(prvState => ({
      likes: prvState.likes + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={e => this.inc()}>{this.state.likes} likes</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LikeBtn /> <LikeBtn /> <LikeBtn /> <LikeBtn /> <LikeBtn /> <LikeBtn />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can add more functionality to `LikeBtn` such as add callback function to return likes to parent component...
look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986326/like-counter-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help